# Mysql optimal ways of taking backup

Tags: database, backup, mysql, database-backups

I have requirement were I want to following things

1. Mysql Full database backup
2. Mysql Incremental backup

Database that I am using is mysql.

Regarding first requirement,i want to take a backup of entire table which includes one transaction table which contains 350  million of data.When trying to backup using mysqldump,load is growing high.So I need a optimal solutions for taking backup

Regarding my second requirement,In daily i want to take a incremental back of a transaction table which is having 350 million data and daily it inserts 10 million data.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the following two questions.  The first deals with the compression side of it, which may assist.  Data Compresses a LOT.  The second deals with and links to a few regarding incremental backup strategies.  I would also augment your original query with some stats - size, frequency, etc.

[Best practices for MySQL backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072938/best-practices-for-mysql-backup)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407124/best-practice-for-backing-up-a-production-mysql-database

Comment: in this particular scarion,are suggesting mysqldump itself??

Comment: @vmb What is scarion?  I refer to GZIP compression in mysqldump.

Comment: once we took backup mysqldump,we got backup file with size 26GB.

Comment: are u meant that lack of compression causing the load??

Comment: It could be.  The longer the drive is busy, the longer things get locked, etc.  I would at least try the compressed backup - it should be around 2GB, which means the drive is relieved sooner - especially if you have some CPU capacity.  See http://bradmcgehee.com/2010/03/08/an-introduction-to-data-compression-in-sql-server-2008/ (See: extra CPU overhead).  Also see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-compression-tuning.html (workload characteristics)

Comment: what about Mysql hot dump??

Comment: Don't know anything about hot dump.  I only work on relatively small MySQL db's and large MsSQL Dbs.

Comment: Anthony,thanks..as you mentioned i will check performance when we have compressuibn

Comment: still i expecting reply from mysql experts

Comment: Also i heard that mysqldump can lock database for a long time with big data